# Stopping Scanner in the end of the line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a file where the first thing is the name of an object, and the other to the end of the line - descriptions for this object, how can i read this using `Scanner`?

```
SUMMARY ; 'Description summary'Description summary2'
CAR ; 'Description car'
SAVINGS ; 'description'
HOME ; 'Description home'
```

I allready have some thing like that. But i need to stop the second `while()` when the line ends.

```
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print(scanner.next());
    scanner.next();
    scanner.useDelimiter("'");
    if(scanner.hasNext(" ")) {
    scanner.next();
        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(" = " + scanner.next());
        }
    }
    if(scanner.hasNextLine()) {scanner.nextLine();}
    scanner.useDelimiter(" ");
    System.out.print("\t");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that I would do it (probably not the best solution) is to call `scanner.nextLine()` to get the entire line of text (before the second `while`, instead of `next()`), then call `split(" ")` to turn it into an array of strings, then iterate through that array to print them.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine ()) {
   String line = scanner.nextLine ();
   String arr [] = line.split (";");
   System.out.print(arr[0] + " = " + arr[1]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it reads the wole line but there may be many descriptions, like in the first line, so im using a `while`. I need something like `if(scanner.hasNext(pattern)) {break;}` but what pattern?